# Create a numbered editor inside a panel or htmleditor

Tags: javascript, extjs, editor

I'm trying to create an app with a database containing examples of scripts that I use in my apps for my personal use.

It is a very simple app: the west region has a grid with the name of the items, and the central region has a hbox with an editor and a panel with my notes.

My difficulty is building the editor. 
The editor can be read only and load the script from database.

I do not need to be as complete as the Sencha Fiddle, the JS Fiddle or the Walking Tree app.

However I needed that has a numbered column on the left, as the editors mentioned above.

Any idea how to do this within a panel or a HTMLEditor or a textarea, or another solution that suits my purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is read only you most likely don't need it to be an editor and you can find some functionality like how here in Stackoverflow you can post code:

```
<div>like this</div>
```

Which I know there are plenty of those out there and probably already include line numbering natively.  For example [Prism](http://prismjs.com/plugins/line-numbers/).

Comment: Thanks ifTrue
I will take a look at Prism